# Visual representation for higher-order functions

Tags: info-visualisation, programming

I'm creating a visual programming language. I base on functional programming paradigm, because I believe that declarative thing should be mapped to visual more easily. I mostly done with conceptual design but there is one thing that I need to make that language full-featured and I still can't come to the solution: higher-order functions (the functions that take one or more other functions as its arguments and do whatever it wants but mostly apply that functions to some data and do something with their outputs).

The best solution I found is one by Autodesk's Max Creation Graph (there is also a [good article](https://area.autodesk.com/blogs/mcgblog/the-function-connector-part-1--reading-mcg-functions) explaining HOF's). Here is how it looks:
[image]
<sub>(source: [autodesk.com](https://area.autodesk.com/userdata/blogs/mcgblog/function_connector_p1/10.png))</sub>

Here `Map` is a higher-order function, stuff in white dashed border is its function argument, orange dot with hint - argument of that "child" function, and the rightmost dark-cyan is the output of "child" function. This solution, however, have some obvious weak points. First of all you need a hand-drawn hint, to figure out where input is. Second - what if you have more than one such unconnected orange dots (e.g. optional arguments)? Or more than one unconnected outputs (e.g. some side-effect functions are used)? And finally, what if "child" function need more then one argument (e.g. for `Map` it can be `element` and `index` so you can not only transform an element of the array but also do something based on it's position in that array) - it's kind of `ಠ_⊙` what the heck will happen in that situation at all...

So, maybe you have some kind of hints, insights or better examples? Or... fresh eye at least.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this question might be best suited for [another stack site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) but I will try to address this on a UX approach alone.

Firstly, if this is a language you are building yourself, I would suggest highlighting the aspects that make your language unique, as to help people better understand it.

If there's nothing unusual about the way higher-order functions operate, and your attached diagram is how you want things to be laid out, try **nesting** your functions visually instead connecting them via a tangle of lines.

Thus, your language would look a bit more like XML, or a dropdown menu, than it would circuitry --in that parts of your function would toggle to show the functions nested within it.

Another approach would be to use those lines more intelligently. Is there a reason why they are a certain color? Could it be that those colors could represent `Map`, `element`, `array`, or `object`? Could the dots at the end have a variety of shapes to show what is being implemented and where? For example, if a function takes an `object` and a `string`, and outputs an `array`, have that function input a yellow triangle, a green square, and output an orange circle.